# Is it possible to embed HTML5 videos from YouTube using the <video>-tag?

Tags: html, youtube, embedding, html5-video

I want to [embed a YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0) on my web page and I want to use it with the `<video>` tag.

How can I do this?

Comment: the video from the link you posted is not visible in my country

Comment: @eznme strange, I'll seek a duplicate video instead. Hold on… Thanks by the way. :)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with their current embed? It is friendly enough that'll even play on Mac stuff (eg: iPhone)

Comment: @NullUserException but I won't be able to use it with the HTML5 JavaScript API which I use all over my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at http://www.youtube.com/html5 and take part in the BETA test.
You can then look how YouTube is working with HTML5 and video.
I'm sure you can find the answers to your questions by looking a bit at the sourcecode :)
I will do that too :D